# Changing line spacing between paragraphs in Word 2003

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2003

I need to format a paper with 2.0 spacing in the paragraphs, but 1.5 line spacing between paragraphs.  How do I make this change without changing the spacing in the paragraphs?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Microsoft took the mainstream view that this would look silly and didn't implement it...

All I can think of to do what you ask for is this, and you shouldn't take it seriously if you have more than one page of text.

- Set Spacing After Paragraph to half your line height (i.e. 6pt for 12pt text) to get the spacing between paragraphs
- leave "Line Spacing" on "Single"
- add manual line breaks (not paragraph breaks) using Shift-Enter at the end of each line of text inside your paragraphs.

Of course this solution defeats the point of a word *processing* software and throws you back into the days of typewriters with manual line breaking...